# ngHide and ngAnimate with max-width: transition property on the wrong class?

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

I'm using ngAnimate to animate max-height for a simple slide-toggle effect, and there's something a bit strange happening: when *hiding*, it seems that setting the transition property on the setup class (`.xxx-hide`) doesn't work--the height snaps to 0 immediately:

```
.controls-hide {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;

  max-height: 5em;
  opacity: 1;
}

.controls-hide.controls-hide-active {
  max-height: 0em;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

But setting it on the *active* class (`.xxx-hide.xxx-hide-active`), the animation works just fine:

```
.othercontrols-hide {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 5em;
}
.othercontrols-hide.othercontrols-hide-active {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;

  max-height: 0em;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

(Here's the [whole fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/abeluga/HB7LU/57/))

Even more strangely, the opacity animates just fine in both cases.  What's going on here?

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior, but I'm setting my transition property in the css of the element itself (in a javascript animation).  I set the property to 'height' (or even 'all') and by the time ng-hide is applied the transition property has been set to 'none'.  I don't have any classes on the element besides ng-hide, and something is overwriting the element inline styles!

Answer (score 1):

I just follow the instructions at this site: http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/appear

And I got this fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/WXWSu/2/

What I changed was set the transtion tag to all changes (`transition: 1s linear all;`), and set the start properties at the main class:

```
.exercise-controls {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;    
    height: 5em;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno--this certainly works fine, but I'd still like to understand WHY the inconsistent behavior in my example...

Comment: Your example has a lot of mistakes. But I think that this behavior is occurring because you are not set the transitions for all changes `transition: 1s linear all`